# Was the scene with Kurt Russell and Kate Hudson created for personal reasons?

Tags: deepwater-horizon

During a climatic scene in [*Deepwater Horizon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1860357/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3), Felicia (portrayed by Kate Hudson) hugs Mr. Jimmy (portrayed Kurt Russell).

The movie never mentions a personal relationship between Mr. Jimmy and Mike Williams (Felicia's husband).  Mr. Jimmy and Mike were shown as strictly having a working relationship.  There were several other survivors shown during this scene who were suggested throughout the movie to have more of a personal relationship with Mike and that Felicia would have known socially.

Although Kurt Russell is not Kate Hudson's biological Father, he has raised her since she was a young child. She regards him as her Father and refers to him as such.

The two of them did not share screen time together, except for this short scene, which did not really seem to make sense to me for the reasons listed above.  I personally believe that if Kurt Russell and Kate Hudson did not have a personal relationship, this scene might not have happened.

**Is there any evidence that filmmakers created this scene for the sole purpose of giving Kurt Russell and Kate Hudson a scene together?**

Answer (score 1):

Kate Hudson's character is married to Mark Wahlberg's character.  Mark Wahlberg's character works for Kurt Russell's character.  I believe the scene was really Felicia hugging Jimmy out of relief and gratitude because it was clear that Mike's relationship with Jimmy changed during the disaster.  Once you go through something so close and personal like that, where you lose people you know, you become more like brothers.

Comment: Yeah...I understand your last sentence.  I just thought that there were other characters with stronger bonds that they could have shown hugging.  It just seemed like an opportunity to get Russell and Hudson on the screen together.  I don't know.  Just my opinion.